MatrixExp sometimes erroneously assumes variables are real
Consider the simple expression
MatrixExp[I Conjugate[x] {{1,0},{0,1}}]

which Mathematica correctly evaluates to
{{E^(I Conjugate[x]), 0}, {0, E^(I Conjugate[x])}}

However, replacing the identity matrix with PauliMatrix[1]:
MatrixExp[I Conjugate[x] {{0,1},{1,0}}]

produces
{{Cos[x], I Sin[x]}, {I Sin[x], Cos[x]}}

which has swallowed the Conjugate[] and erroneously treated x as real. It is as if MatrixExp has invoked ComplexExpand behind the scenes.
It is easy to show the input and output to MatrixExp disagree in general:
g[x_] :=  MatrixExp[I Conjugate[x] {{0,1},{1,0}}];
f[x_] = g[x];

y = .1 + .2 I;
f[y] - g[y] // Chop

>>> {{0. - 0.0402001 I, -0.40066}, {-0.40066, 0. - 0.0402001 I}}

I'm using Mathematica version 13.0.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (January 28, 2022). Is this a bug, or a problem in my understanding?

Indeed it does call ComplexExpand: Trace[MatrixExp[I  Conjugate[x]  {{0, 1}, {1, 0}}],  _ComplexExpand,  TraceInternal -> True]

Possible workaround: Block[{ComplexExpand = # &},   MatrixExp[I  Conjugate[x]  {{0, 1}, {1, 0}}]]

@MichaelE2 What kind of syntax ComplexExpand = # & is?

@azerbajdzan, it redefines ComplexExpand as an "identity function" (just return the input).

@Domen So it could be ComplexExpand = Identity. But why it does not throw an error like it would outside of the Block? Is it documented usage?

@azerbajdzan Compare Block[{ComplexExpand = # &},   ComplexExpand[Exp[I  t], TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}]] and
Block[{ComplexExpand = Identity},   ComplexExpand[Exp[I  t], TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}]]. # & is more versatile, as it returns the first argument, no matter how many arguments there are. If ComplexExpand has just one argument, then there's no difference. A long, long time ago, I noticed you can redefined Protected (but not Locked) symbols with Block. I don't recall if it's documented.

There is a workaround in 14.0 on Windows 10.
MatrixFunction[ Exp[I*Conjugate[#*x] ] &, {{0, 1}, {1, 0}}] // FullSimplify


{{Cos[Conjugate[x]], I Sin[Conjugate[x]]}, {I Sin[Conjugate[x]],  Cos[Conjugate[x]]}}

